# AFNetworking - only load from cache if server responded http header status 304?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I have a question about using AFNetworking with SDURLCache.

In my application. I can see they work together fine, for repeated queries, responses from local cache will be used correctly.

But, let's say the server xml is updated one minute ago, in my app, cache is still used.

This doesn't match my client's expectation, the client's expectation is:
I need to check http header, if it is 200, load the file from server, if it is 304 (not modified), just use local cache from disk/

Any chance this is a built-in behaviour? Or I have to manually hack the class somewhere so that it can behave like this?

Comment: I am running the same issue, have you resolved your case ?

Comment: hi Malloc, sadly, no. my client accepted the fact that content will be cached for awhile later.

Comment: Hi dunforget, so you didn't use the returned code to check for new version? did you request new version periodically? some adopt that approach. Please share, thanx :)

Comment: Hi Malloc, this was quite awhile ago and I only roughly remember that the AFNetworking+SDURLCache will automatically respect the "expiration" properties in the HTTP header responded from server. It was about 30 minutes for that server I was working on. Therefore I never check status header anymore. So, for example, if someone loaded the content at 12.30PM but the content is updated at 12.45PM, when the user revisit the app in 12.50PM, because the cached content may still be "fresh" (20 minutes old) so that SDURLCache will load the cached content.